# Use mat-button-toggle-group with content projection

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to achieve the following:
I got a wrapper component which has a mat-button-toggle-group. In this toggle-group there should be buttons. But I want to control which buttons are there from outside via content projection into the wrapper component. Of course I could make ngIf´s but this takes a bit of flexibility.

So I want to be able to do something like this:

Any component:

```
<action-bar>
    <button-one></button-one>
    <button-two></button-two>
</action-bar>
```

Another component:

```
<action-bar>
    <button-two></button-two>
    <button-three></button-three>
</action-bar>
```

The buttons `<button-one>, <button-two>` ... would be just components which contain a real `<mat-button-toggle>` like this

```
<mat-button-toggle value="bold">Bold</mat-button-toggle>
```

I created a stackblitz which shows the problem:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vryx72?file=src/app/bold-button/bold-button.component.html
Here the bold button is added to the toggle-group via content projection but when I click on it, it doesn´t change the value of the toggle-group

Anyone has an idea how to achieve that?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further what you would like to have inside those different buttons later? An idea could be to create a custom structural directive which you would use to create ur mat-toggle-buttons. But if that could really be an option would depend on what you would like to achieve in the end.

Comment: Added more information. Is that enough? In the components there is one mat-button-toggle each. You can check out the stackblitz which shows it as well.

Comment: Will those buttons really just contain the real `mat-button-toggle`? In what would they actually differ? Will it just be the value or something else?

Comment: Yes they will differ in value, content (there are images on each button), and tooltips mainly. I think the problem is the content projection which destroys the link between mat-button-toggle-group and mat-button-toggle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because content projection breaks the link between `mat-button-toggle-group` and `mat-button-toggle`, we need to export and pass around the `matButtonToggleGroup` component. This is kinda brittle but it should get you what you want. I updated your stackblitz, but I also forked my own which you should be able to view here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vryx72-m6u2f1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbutton-toggle-overview-example.ts

Below is the code need to project content into a mat-button-toggle-group and have the control model use the projected content.

```
// action-bar.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: "action-bar",
  template: `
      <mat-button-toggle-group 
        name="toggleButtonGroup"
        #matButtonToggleGroup="matButtonToggleGroup">
          <ng-content></ng-content>
          <mat-button-toggle value="italic">Italic</mat-button-toggle>
          <mat-button-toggle value="underline">Underline</mat-button-toggle>
      </mat-button-toggle-group>
  `,
  // export ActionBar component so we can access the `buttonToggleGroup` viewChild property
  exportAs: "actionBar"
})
export class ButtonToggleOverviewExample {
  @ViewChild("matButtonToggleGroup", { static: true }) 
  buttonToggleGroup: MatButtonToggleGroup;
}
```

```
// button-two.component.ts

@Component({
  selector: "button-two",
  template: `
    <mat-button-toggle value="bold" #buttonToggle="matButtonToggle">
      bold
    </mat-button-toggle>
  `
})
export class ButtonTwoComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() buttonToggleGroup: MatButtonToggleGroup;

  @ViewChild("buttonToggle", { static: true }) 
  matButtonToggle: MatButtonToggle;

  // Assign the parent matButtonToggleGroup to the viewChild matButtonToggle property. This links the projected matButtonToggle back to the parent button group.
  ngOnInit() {
    this.matButtonToggle.buttonToggleGroup = this.matButtonGroup;
  }
}
```

```
// app.html

<action-bar #actionBar="actionBar">
    <button-two [buttonToggleGroup]="actionBar.buttonToggleGroup"></button-two>
    <button-three [buttonToggleGroup]="actionBar.buttonToggleGroup"></button-three>
</action-bar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try another one as I am already using ngrx/component-store here. But this gave me some good hints :)